# Show list without using a button, with knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have this code to show a list when a button is clicked. How can I make the list show without clicking the button?

```
<button class="btn"  type="submit" data-bind="click: getList">Get List</button>
<ul data-bind="foreach: pList">
    <li>
        <b data-bind="text: $data"></b>  
    </li>
</ul>

define(['sublime/aadConfig','knockout'], function (aconfig,ko) {
    var plugins = ko.observableArray([]);

    var getPlugins = function () { 
        plugins(aconfig.getPluginList());
    };

    return {
        pList: plugins,
        getList: getPlugins
    };
});
```

Comment: Please, English only (solo Ingles).

Comment: There is proposal for a Spanish StackOverflow, you might be interested: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish

Answer (score 2):

If you want the list to load without having to click the button you just need to call getPlugins;

```
define(['sublime/aadConfig','knockout'], function (aconfig,ko) {
    var plugins = ko.observableArray([]);

    var getPlugins = function () {

        plugins(aconfig.getPluginList());
    };

    getPlugins(); //<-- This will go populate your plugins observable, which should auto populate your list.

    return {
        pList: plugins,
        getList: getPlugins
    };   
});
```

**EDIT**

If you have objects in your array then that would happen as you specified to show $data in your markup.

[{text:"someText"},{text:"someText"},{text:"someText"}] <-- this would output [object Object]

["sometext","sometext","sometext"] <-- would output "sometext"

**So its sound like you need to say $data.myDesiredValue or just myDesiredValue in your markup rather than $data**

Comment: instead of my list came this:[object Object], I think that should put activate

Answer (score 0):

a quick solution if you have jQuery but not so pretty :

```
$(function(){
    $('button.btn').click();
```

});